# NodeJS subprocess.send() fails silently

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm using `child_process.fork()` to spawn a child process, but calls from the parent to child via `subprocess.send()` fail silently (despite happening inside `subprocess.on('spawn')` callback); specifically, the child's `process.on('message')` does not trigger. Strangely, calls from the child to parent via `process.send()` work just fine. The call to subprocess.send returns `true`, which, according to the docs means it was successful; and no error is triggered from the child.

Parent.js:

```
const subprocess = fork(…);
subprocess.on('error', console.error);
subprocess.on('message', console.log);
// subprocess.on(eventName, console.log) for all other events
subprocess.on('spawn', () => {
  subprocess.send({ hello: 'child' }); // return's boolean `true`
});
```

Sub.js:

```
process.on('message', console.log); // nothin'
process.send({ hello: 'parent' }); // ← parent's on message triggered
```

Both `subprocess.connected` and the child's `process.connected` are `true`

Comment: Works for me. Child process receives message from parent `{ hello: 'child' }`. If you add `subprocess.on('message', console.log);` in your parent.js, then you'll see a message sent by child process, which is `{ hello: 'parent' }`.

Comment: I have subprocess.on('message', console.log) (see comment about all other events having it in my sample code above)

Comment: which node version are you testing on? The code needs at least node 15, because - according to node's docs -`spawn` event was introduced just then.

Comment: I'm on V15.11.0

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: I'm using the same, 15.11.0. Your code works perfectly fine on my machine. Just added `subprocess.on('message', console.log);` in parent.js

Comment: Parent.js already has that

Comment: It's a race condition: the child's `process.on('message')` has not happened when subprocess.send (inside `subprocess.on('spawn')`) is called. Wrapping the `subprocess.send()` in a setTimeout with ~30ms delay causes the child's message handler to trigger most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and has existed since the `spawn` event was added in v15.1: [nodejs/node#37782](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37782)

It occurs only with ESM (`import`) and not commonjs (`require`).